# How to get the timestamp of a file in a repository using JGit?

Tags: java, git, jgit

Is there any way to get timestamp of changed files, deleted files, newly added files from JGit? I have below code which walks the tree and get me these files but I am not able to figure out how can I get the timestamp of those files.

```
  public static Map<String, Object> diffFormatter(Git git, ObjectId lastCommitId) {
    Map<String, Object> m = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    DiffFormatter formatter = new DiffFormatter(out);
    formatter.setRepository(git.getRepository());
    AbstractTreeIterator commitTreeIterator = prepareTreeParser(git.getRepository(), lastCommitId);
    FileTreeIterator workTreeIterator = new FileTreeIterator(git.getRepository());
    List<DiffEntry> diffEntries = formatter.scan(commitTreeIterator, workTreeIterator);
    Set<String> changedFiles = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> newlyAddedFiles = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> deletedFiles = new HashSet<String>();
    if (diffEntries.size() < 1) {
      return m;
    }
    for (DiffEntry entry : diffEntries) {
      if (entry.getChangeType().name().equals(ChangeType.ADD.name())) {
        newlyAddedFiles.add(entry.getNewPath());
        // newlyAddedFiles.add(entry.getNewPath() + ":" + "file_timestamp");
      } else if (entry.getChangeType().name().equals(ChangeType.DELETE.name())) {
        deletedFiles.add(entry.getOldPath());
        // deletedFiles.add(entry.getOldPath() + ":" + "file_timestamp");
      } else {
        formatter.format(entry);
        changedFiles.add(entry.getNewPath());
        // changedFiles.add(entry.getNewPath() + ":" + "file_timestamp");
      }
    }
    m.put(Constants.CHANGED_FILE_STR, changedFiles);
    m.put(Constants.NEWLY_ADDED_FILE_STR, newlyAddedFiles);
    m.put(Constants.DELETED_FILE_STR, deletedFiles);
    return m;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git does not store file modification timestamps. What is stored, however, is when the commit was created.

This information can be obtained with `RevCommit::getCommitTime()`